# How to reorder NSMutableDictionary to a NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `NSMutableArray` containing `NSURLConnection` descriptions, like so:

```
array {

    "<NSURLConnection: 0x60eb40>",
    "<NSURLConnection: 0x6030e0>",
    "<NSURLConnection: 0x602ce0>",
    "<NSURLConnection: 0x60c330>",
    "<NSURLConnection: 0x662f5a0>",
}
```

I have also a `NSMutableDictionary` whose keys are the items from the above `NSMutableArray`, like so:

```
dictionary {

"<NSURLConnection: 0x602ce0>"  = "Last update: Sep 3, 2012";
"<NSURLConnection: 0x6030e0>"  = "Last update: Sep 7, 2012";
"<NSURLConnection: 0x60c330>"  = "Last update: Sep 4, 2012";
"<NSURLConnection: 0x60eb40>"  = "Last update: Sep 6, 2012";
"<NSURLConnection: 0x662f5a0>" = "Last update: Sep 5, 2012";
```

}

**I need to reorder the `NSMutableDictionary` to match the same order of the `NSMutableArray` `indexes`.** Right now I'm doing like this:

```
int a;
for (a=0; a<self.array.count; a++) {

    NSString *key    = [self.array objectAtIndex:a];
    NSString *object = [self.dictionary objectForKey:key];

    if (object !=nil) {
        [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:a];
        [self.array insertObject:object atIndex:a];
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to reorder this `NSMutableDicitioanry` to match the order of the `NSMutableArray` ?

Thank you!

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered. What is your larger goal?

Comment: Also, `NSURLConnection` doesn't conform to `NSCopying`. How are you using those as keys?

Comment: I wrote an answer, but the correct answer is "what are you trying to do?", as @W'rkncacnter said

Comment: I have multiple asynchronous NSURLConnections that I need to keep track. The ultimate goal is have an ordered NSArray of dates to be displayed on a UITableView. The problem is that the dates won't show in the proper oder, due to the nature of the asynchronous connection. So I keep track of the connections in an Array, and store the responses containing the dates on a dictionary. Then the final dictionary will never match the oder of the array. That's why I need a new ordered array whose indexes wil match the first one containing the NSURLConnection descriptions.

Comment: I'm just using the keys to maintain the same order as the NSURLConnections occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDictionary` does not guarantee any ordering of it's key/value pairs. There's no way to keep your keys/values in a set order and it doesn't make sense for `NSDictionary` to work like this. (You use *keys* not *indexes* to retrieve values).

If you want your values or keys in a certain order for display purposes you can sort them after retrieving them:

```
NSArray * sortedKeys = [ [ myDictionary allKeys ] sortedArrayUsingSelector:... ] ;
```

or

```
NSArray * sortedKeys = [ [ myDictionary allKeys ] sortedArrayUsingComparator:... ] ;
```

You could then retrieve the associated objects for the sorted keys if you wanted.

Another option is to maintain 2 separate arrays, one for keys and one for values and keep them in order.

Comment: I have multiple asynchronous NSURLConnections that I need to keep track. The ultimate goal is have an ordered NSArray of dates to be displayed on a UITableView. The problem is that the dates won't show in the proper oder, due to the nature of the asynchronous connection. So I keep track of the connections in an Array, and store the responses containing the dates on a dictionary. Then the final dictionary will never match the oder of the array. That's why I need a new ordered array whose indexes wil match the first one containing the NSURLConnection descriptions.